# MEAN - `post` giving error message on test with Postman, not able to predict the issue.

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack, postman

I am working with `MEAN` app, I have created a post request with `name,username,password` - i am trying to test this using the `postman` chrome add-on.

But I am always getting an error instead of my data posted.
i am connecting with `db` like this:

```
mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://jbarif:root@ds147975.mlab.com:47975/family', function( err ) {

    if( err ) console.log( err );

    console.log( 'connection successful!' ); //getting consoled

} );
```

posting the data like this:

```
"use strict";

var User = require('../models/userModel');

module.exports = function( express, app ){

    var openApi = express.Router();

    openApi.post('/create', function( req, res ){

        var user = new User();

        var name = req.body.name;
        var username = req.body.username;
        var password = req.body.password;

        console.log( name, username, password  + '\n' + user );


        user.save(function(err) {

            if (err) {

                // duplicate entry
                if (err.code == 11000)

                    return res.json({ success: false, message: 'A user with that username already exists. '});

                else

                    return res.send(err); //always getting this!
            }

            res.json({ message: 'User created!' });
        });

    });

    //prefixing the open apis
    app.use('/open', openApi);

    return openApi;

}
```

here is the error from `postman` :

```
{
    "message": "User validation failed",
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "errors": {
        "password": {
            "message": "Path `password` is required.",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "type": "required",
                "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
                "path": "password"
            },
            "kind": "required",
            "path": "password"
        },
        "username": {
            "message": "Path `username` is required.",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "type": "required",
                "message": "Path `{PATH}` is required.",
                "path": "username"
            },
            "kind": "required",
            "path": "username"
        }
    }
}
```

for your knowledge here is my `server.js` :

```
var 
    express     = require('express'),
    path        = require('path'),
    morgan      = require('morgan'),
    bodyParser  = require('body-parser'),
    port        = process.env.PORT || 8080,
    mongoose    = require('mongoose'),
    openApi     = require('./app/api/openApi'),
    familyApi   = require('./app/api/familyApi'),
    app         = express();

    //app config;-

var base        = app.use( express.static( __dirname + '/public') );
var reqest      = app.use( morgan('dev') );
var jsonParse   = app.use( bodyParser.json() );
var urlParse    = app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://jbarif:root@ds147975.mlab.com:47975/family', function( err ) {

    if( err ) console.log( err );

    console.log( 'connection successful!' );

} );
// mongoose.connect('mongodb://node:noder@ds013456.mlab.com:13456/practical');

    //calling api from another files;
    openApi( express, app );
    familyApi( express, app );


    app.get('/', function( req, res ) {
        res.sendFile( path.join( __dirname + '/public/app/views/index.html') );
    });

    app.get('*', function( req, res, next ) {
        return res.status(404).json({success: false, message: 'Route \'' + req.url + '\' is invalid.'});
    });

    app.listen( port );
    console.log('app is listening at', port );
```

Comment: sample body of request that you are making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose validation is failing because you have nothing in user object.

change it to :

```
var userData = {name: req.body.name, username: req.body.username,  password:req.body.password};

var user = new User(userData);
```